# OS X application manager

Tags: mac-appstore, homebrew, macports, package-management, fink

Unix-sytled, "package managers" like [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew), and [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) do a good job of managing 'headless' libraries.  I would like something similar to manage OS X applications with a GUI.

I am hoping to find an easier way to add/remove applications and restore my system in the event of loss or theft or if I purchase a new computer.

Requirements:

- find and install applications
- keep track of which applications I've installed
- uninstall applications and preferences
- manage licenses

Candidates:

- [AppFresh for Mac](http://metaquark.de/appfresh/mac) - best candidate; not free
- [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask) - good candidate; limited application support
- [Apple's App Store](http://www.apple.com/osx/apps/app-store.html) - easily find and install applications; doesn't remove applications; not all applications are in the App Store
- [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) - removes applications and preferences, but does not install applications
- [osx.iusethis.com](http://osx.iusethis.com/) - tracks application (which will replace my spreadsheet); does not manage applications

Are there others?

Comment: There is [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask), but it only includes about 150 applications at the moment.

Comment: Who told you that you couldn't remove applications installed with the MAS?  You should not listen to them any more.  Open Launchpad, click-and-hold on the application, then click the X.  Same as iOS.

Answer (score 1):

[Bodega](http://appbodega.com/) can install, check for updates, and uninstall. It also has ability to search for new applications based on your search terms and/or category. It's pretty good, but it is not all-inclusive.

[Macupdate Desktop](https://www.macupdate.com/desktop/) is shareware that is similar to Bodega, but has no feature to uninstall applications as far as I know.